Cannot install git on Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS after upgrade
I had git installed but after an upgrade (Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS) it is removed and cannot cannot be installed anymore. the following error appears.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git : Depends: git-man (< 1:2.43.0-.) but 1:2.46.0-0ppa1~ubuntu22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
I already checked internet and tried various options (including removing ppa), but without success.

You write that you disable or deleted ("removed") the PPA. Did you uninstall the packages that came from that PPA?

Remove the PPA, remove all packages from that PPA, run sudo apt update, and then run sudo apt install git

Thanks for the suggestions. It works now after following the instructions on 'How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?', as suggested by Karel. Thanks a lot.
(I am familiar with Linux, but not a real expert.
What I mean with 'git was removed' is that git was installed and worked well on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, but after the update to 24.04.1 LTS, GIT was not found (removed). I tried some possible solutions like
'sudo apt install ppa-purge', 'sudo ppa-purge ppa:git-core/ppa',
'sudo apt update', 'sudo apt install git'. However, this did not solve the problem.)
